# Ada How to Convert an Integer to Binary in Ada and put the result in an array

Tags: ada

I would like to use an array to contain the binary result. if the input of i is 11, I expected the output could be binary of 11, which is 1011. and the binary array has an element [[1011]]. In python, it works like

```
    int i;
    temp = bin(i)
    binary =[]
    binary = binary + [temp[2:]]
```

I used a vector for binary array in Ada in order to contain the result, which is converted to array. because I do not use Ada.Text_IO.Put so I don't know what else I should provide about my ada code.

```
package binary is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Natural, Integer);
```

Comment: What code have you tried writing in Ada?

Comment: I re-edit my question is that what you are asking.  I am sorry that I cannot express it correctly.

Comment: You will find help more forthcoming if you provide more information. Your Python example is incomplete. What is `i`? What is `templist`? Show us some input and then what the expected output is. Your Ada code shows very little effort, but SO can maybe help further if we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: More context would also be welcome; for example, [`Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html#p18) converts an `Integer` to a `String`—an `array of Character`—which might be a useful step.

Answer (score 1):

The Python `temp = bin(11)` produces the string result `’0b1011’` so what I guess you want (and it’s only a guess, because you say you want an array, but that’s *not* what the Python does) is the string `’1011’`.

This code, perhaps longer than it need be because I’ve not used `use`, does more-or-less the equivalent:

```ada
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Fixed;
procedure Wang is
   Temp : String (1 .. 35);
begin
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put (Temp, 11, Base => 2);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Temp);
   declare
      Trimmed : constant String := Ada.Strings.Fixed.Trim
        (Temp, Ada.Strings.Both);
   begin
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Trimmed (Trimmed'First + 2  .. Trimmed'Last - 1));
   end;
end Wang;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by "*I would like to use an array to contain the binary result except first two.*" -- I'm going to assume that you mean that you want the binary-representation of the integer, except the "first two bits", as an array of Boolean.

```
Type Bit_Vector is Array(Positive range <>) of Boolean
  with Component_Size => 1;

-- For testing purposes.
Function Image( Input : Bit_Vector ) return String is
    Function Internal(Object : Bit_Vector:= Input) return String is
      (case Object'Length is
           when 0 => "",
           when 1 => (1 => (if Object(Object'First) then '1' else '0')),
           when others =>
              Internal((1=>Object(Object'First))) & -- ',' &
              Internal(Object(Positive'Succ(Object'First)..Object'Last))
      ) with Inline;
Begin
    Return '(' & Internal(Input) & ')';
End;

-- Convert an integer to a bit-vector.
Function To_Bits( Input : Integer ) return Bit_Vector is
    -- We need a constrained subtype to instantiate
    -- the Unchecked_Conversion generic; fortunately, we 
    -- can contain everything nested in the procedure.
    Subtype Constrained_Bits is Bit_Vector(1..Integer'Size);
    Function Convert is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(
       Source => Integer,
       Target => Constrained_Bits
      );
Begin
    Return Convert(Input);
End To_Bits;

Type Direction is (Front, Back);

-- This filters out the indicated number of bits,
-- but from the indicated side.
Function Filter( Value  : Bit_Vector;
                 Amount : Positive;
                 Side   : Direction:= Front
               ) return Bit_Vector is
  (if Side = Front  -- We can trim either side.
   then Value(Value'First+Amount..Value'Last)
   else Value(Value'First..Value'Last-Amount)
  );
  
X : Constant Bit_Vector:= To_Bits( 16#0000_FFFF# );
Y : Bit_Vector renames Filter(X, 12);

Begin
   Ada.Test_IO.Put_Line( Y );
End;
```

Comment: For the last Begin "Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Y)" There is an error "missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "put_Line" declared"/ "no candidate interpretations match the actuals" Is there anything I need to pay attention to?

Comment: @wangkom -- Should be: `Put_Line( Image(Y) )`.